# how to get just one item from array of strings if the other is the same

Tags: java

I want to know if there is a function in Java retrieve one string from  array of strings  if the other strings are the same i.e. if I have in my array : 
yes,yes,yes,yes,no,no,no,no .. I want to get only one yes and one no and display them!
and not by using for loop and comparing ! , just I want to know if this function exists in Java .

Comment: Just add them to `Set<String>` - it will take care of duplicates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert all those into a Set.Then u will get like that

```
String[] array = {"yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","no"};
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Set does not allow duplicates.

Finally the set contains `yes` and `no`(only 2 elements)

Answer (score 2):

If this is your array

```
String[] a = {"yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","no"};
```

then this will display unique values

```
   System.out.println(new HashSet(Arrays.asList(a)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Dump your array into a set and use that:

```
Set uniqueStrings = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(yourArray));
```

If you need it as array again you can use

```
String[] uniqueStringsArray = uniqueStrings.toArray(new String[uniqueStrings.size()]);
```

Internally, this iterates through the array and compares the Strings. You cannot avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this

```
    String[] arr=new String[]{"yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","no"};
    Object[] unique = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr)).toArray();
    System.out.println(unique[0]);
    System.out.println(unique[1]);
```